# splitting file based on values in specific column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file that I would like to break up into multiple files with uniq values for the first column. For example, here is a file:

fileA.txt

```
1    Cat
1    Dog
1    Frog
2    Boy
2    Girl
3    Tree
3    Leaf
3    Branch
3    Trunk
```

I would like my output to look something like this:

file1.txt

```
1    Cat
2    Boy
3    Tree
```

file2.txt

```
1    Dog
2    Girl
3    Leaf
```

file3.txt

```
1    Frog
3    Branch
```

file4.txt

```
3    Trunk
```

If a value does not exist, I want it to be skipped. I have tried to search for similar situations to mine, but I've come up short. Does anyone have idea of how to do this?

**Edit:** My awk version is: `awk version 20070501`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ gawk '{print > "file" ++a[$1] ".txt"}' input

# And on OSX awk, and also gawk:

$ awk '{print > ("file" ++a[$1] ".txt")}' input


$ head file*txt
==> file1.txt <==
1    Cat
2    Boy
3    Tree

==> file2.txt <==
1    Dog
2    Girl
3    Leaf

==> file3.txt <==
1    Frog
3    Branch

==> file4.txt <==
3    Trunk
```

*edit*: An explanation. 
This prints the current line into (`>`) `fileX.txt`. Every time the first field is found, an array `a[$1]` is increased by 1 before it is evaluated. This is used to establish the file name.

*edit 2*:
I do not have the possibility to check with OSX awk, but I guess if you are halfly serious about using awk, you would do good installing `gawk` or `mawk`. You could, however, give this a shot:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++; f = "file" a[$1] ".txt"; print > f}' input
```

This does the same, but all the action is split in separate steps. This is to help OSX awk to understand the right order of evaluating the parts.

Comment: When I attempted this solution, I got this error `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print > >>>  "file"++ <<< ` The actual column in my file that I am sorting by is column 6. Therefore I changed the array to `a[$6]`. Was this incorrect?

Comment: I changed the answer a bit, and added some spacing. Make sure there is a space between `"file"` and `++a[$6]`, and that there is no space between `++` and `a[$6]`. If that does not work, please reveal what `awk --version` says.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.. I've edited my original post with my awk version.

Comment: The most important question is, what kind of `awk`. According to Wikipedia, these are the implementations: `BWK`, `gawk`, `mawk`, `awka`, `tawk`, `Jawk`, `jawk`, `xgawk`, `QSEAWK`, `BusyBox`

Comment: I use `awk` for most of my needs. However, this does not seem to work. Very disappointing. I think it has something to do with me being on a mac :(

Comment: @stellar01: I updated the answer with a guess. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: This is what seemed to work: `awk '{print > ("file" ++a[$1] ".txt")}' input`